# unable to access my user account

Tags: 14.04, lts

i had a new operating system installed on my computer ( linux ) i'm not familiar with the program. always had windows. one of the problems i am now  having, amongst others is, i am only able to use my computer through my guest account, all the icons are visible on the left side of the screen. i do not need to enter password to access this account. a window opens up saying all data will be deletedand when i shut down the computer and come back to it the next day any thing that was done the previous day is gone.
 when i switch back to my user account, i enter my password, the the wallpaper changes, but then i do not have any icons to the left of my screen to work with. could i have touched the wrong button.
i also do not have any administrative privileges to do anything and i do not have the installation disk

```
                   HELP ...
```

Comment: Try after reboot, and update me

Comment: I'm sorry but your description of the problem does not give enough information to help you. It's going to be really difficult to diagnose that without seeing the machine, but we can try if you give us more information. What does this “display screen” look like? (Normally I'd ask for a screenshot, but you probably can't take a screenshot, so take a good-quality picture.) How were things different when you could access your account? What changed — what did you do between the time it last worked and the time it first didn't work?

Comment: You can still access your system as long as you have physical access to it. But I'm guessing that having command line access won't help you much. We can help you repair your system, but you need to help us help you.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommand a new and fresh install.

You can backup your files when you boot from USB before re-installing. [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) is a guide.